# Pandas - Merging rows in pandas based on certain columns where rows are of both of string and float type

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So I have this data set where I have 7 columns, of which 4 columns have the same data for a subset of rows. The data looks something like in this image.

[image: Initial DataFrame]

Here you can see how 'ID' , 'innings', 'overs' and 'BattingTeam' stay the same for 6 rows and then the 'overs' column changes in value while others remain the same from these 4.

The other columns i.e 'batter' 'bowler' and 'total_run' are the ones which I have to enclose in one single row.

I tried using groupby() and apply method using join, however was not able to get the exact results I was expecting. The answer that I am expecting looks something like this:

[image: Expected DataFrame]

I also tried to remove duplicates using drop.duplicates(), that also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary to specify how you want to aggregate each column; in this case you want the unique values from `batter`, the `sum` of `total_run`, and any value from `bowler` and `BattingTeam`, which you can get using `min` (for example).

```py
agg_dict = { 'batter' : lambda g:list(set(g)),
    'bowler' : min,
    'total_run' : sum,
    'BattingTeam' : min
}
df.groupby(['ID', 'innings', 'overs'], as_index=False).agg(agg_dict)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
        ID  innings  overs                     batter          bowler  total_run       BattingTeam
0  1312200        1      0  [JC Buttler, YBK Jaiswal]  Mohammed Shami          2  Rajasthan Royals
1  1312200        1      1  [JC Buttler, YBK Jaiswal]      Yash Dayal          5  Rajasthan Royals
```

If you want a comma separated list for `batter`, change the aggregation function to:

```py
'batter' : lambda g:', '.join(set(g))
```

Output:

```
        ID  innings  overs                   batter          bowler  total_run       BattingTeam
0  1312200        1      0  JC Buttler, YBK Jaiswal  Mohammed Shami          2  Rajasthan Royals
1  1312200        1      1  JC Buttler, YBK Jaiswal      Yash Dayal          5  Rajasthan Royals
```